# Detecting certain colliders on my game object with OnTriggerEnter2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I have an enemy game object with 2 triggers attached to it. What I want to achieve is that the enemy will do a separate attack depending on which trigger the player has collided with. So there is a left trigger and a right trigger and these triggers have been saved into a public array on the enemy game object. Here is the code that I thought would achieve the goal however, the if else statement always returns false when it should be returning true.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "ThePlayer")
        {
            if (collision == DamageTriggers[0])
            {
                LeftClawAttack();
            }
            else if (collision == DamageTriggers[1])
            {
                RightClawAttack();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("False");
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone can show me what I am doing wrong here and help me to find a solution to this problem it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you checked that your DamageTriggers array got populated? also what sort of array is the DamageTriggers?

Comment: The damage triggers are definently populated. The arrays are BoxCollider2D's. Should this code work? If so then I've probably made a tiny mistake that I've overlooked.

Comment: i will try it myself and come back to you, i think the problem is because you are comparing colliders and not collisions.

Comment: Okay thank you. I think you are correct with the problem being that I'm comparing colliders and not collisions. I'm not sure on how I would tell the program to compare the collisions rather then the colliders though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jadon Wolfgang I have been able to figure out why my code wasn't working. So the problem was that I was comparing Box Colliders and not collisions, so to fix this problem I found that you can use a function called *IsTouching()*

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "ThePlayer")
        {
            if (DamageTriggers[0].IsTouching(collision))
            {
                LeftClawAttack();
            }
            else if (DamageTriggers[1].IsTouching(collision))
            {
                RightClawAttack();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("False");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the new code if anyone else was having a similar problem.

Comment: I already thought that you should need to do something like that. i'm glad you have found the problem